# Geometric intuition of bounded trajectory and connectedness

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

> Property of Omega-limit set:
>
> Let x be a point on a manifold and $\Psi_{t}\left ( x \right )$ be a trajectory through x. If $\Psi_{t}\left ( x \right )$ is bounded, then the omega limit set $L_{\omega}$ is connected.

Could anyone be kind enough to provide a simple illustration for me to wrap my head around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do find an example of an unbounded trajectory with a nonconnected omega limit set. You'll then see why boundedness is crucial.